# How to make a dynamic table layout using XML

Tags: android, dynamic

I want to make a table layout as shown in the below screen:

[image]

I am able to make this UI using the code. But I want to make it using the XML. I tried the following approach.

I tried to make a tablelayout which will have header and title. Now I have two row below title which is getting repeated. 
So I made these two rows in separate XML file named row1 and row2. But Now I don't know how to integrate these three in  the code. I know there is method `LayoutInflater.inflate()` to do it but I have two rows with diff kind of layout. See below the code for two rows. Please suggest What approach I should follow to make this kind of UI.

**ROW_1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/table_row"
android:minHeight="30dip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/light_grey"
android:clickable="true"

>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:text="column1"  
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
 />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2" 
    android:text="column2"   
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    />

       <TextView android:id="@+id/tv3" 
    android:text="column3"   
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    />  

</TableRow>
```

**ROW_2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/table_row"
android:minHeight="30dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/light_grey"
android:clickable="true"
>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:text="short description text for Title 0 comes here"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"

 /> 
</TableRow>
```

Comment: could you not use a ListView instead. you can supply different xml for different rows.

Comment: where I can paste my image in order to provide the link? What is benefit of gridview over a table layout. I can make the UI using the code But I think its better to make it using the xml because any change in UI  in future will require to change the xml part only. But don't know how to make it using the xml.

Comment: @Sam Quest: Does List View give the same looks like a table. I need to make a table where first row contain 3 column. 2nd row contain one column spanning all the three row. Now I need to consider these two rows as a single element. and it goes on repeating. Will a listview be suitable for this kind of view.

Comment: then can you consider the two rows as one ListItem (one row). is the number of rows already known?

Comment: @Sam Quest: No. of rows are initially not known. Data would be coming from the server.

Comment: check my answer. in the meantime do you have any user interaction with those rows.

Comment: Yes I do have the user interaction. User will click on the row and He will be directed to next screen after fetching some data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from looking at the image i would suggest taking the list view route. have your layout as

```
R1Col1     R1Col2     R1Col3
R2 Looooong Col1
```

this should workout well for you.

**UPDATE**

you list_item.xml should look something like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:text="column1"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2" 
            android:text="column2"   
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv3" 
            android:text="column3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="short description text for Title 0 comes here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is a sample to learn how to populate a ListView

[ListView Example](https://github.com/sudar/android-samples/blob/master/Week2HomeWork/src/com/sudarmuthu/android/homework/week2/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try this approach. I have one more question. My UI does have two more component above the UI which I have posted. one is drop down and other is date picker. now I want when user will scroll then complete page should scroll instead of only a list view. Is is possible to do it.

Comment: if you see the market app (not the new WP style). the main page has that behavior (it has the gallery in the first row). i think you can try setting those two in the header/first row of the ListView. and you have to make them 'Clickable' to receive the user's touch.

Comment: Can you provide a link where I can make this kind of layout in list view. I googled it but could not know how to make it in list view.

Comment: Thanks for updating me about the link accepting the answer. Definitly do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need two different rows ?

You can integrate two rows in one Xml and so you have only one row to add in table view

Comment: I also tried the approach you are suggesting. But on interating the two rows, I am not able to make the layout which i require. The row1 only shows the one textview while I need the three. Row2 shows one row.