# How to create a table above other list

Tags: android, listview, tablelayout

I want to create a UI as shown in the below link:

http://i53.tinypic.com/sxksx5.jpg

According to me there can be the following approaches to do it.

**There are two tables in this image. The above table should be made in the following way:**

One row with two textview in one xml file. Now Inflate this UI using LayoutInflater. Draw It using a loop and set the text according to requirement.

**The below table should be made in the following way:**

[How to make a dynamic table layout using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226779/android-how-to-make-a-dynamic-table-layout-using-xml)

see the above link where It is advised that the 2nd table should be made using the listview.

Now I am confused that this can be made using **gridvew, tablelayout, listview.** Which one I should prefer and why? In my previous projects I have made this kind of UI almost in the coding. But I believe that a little change in the UI will require lot of change in the code. So I want to make the current UI using the xml. But dont know what approach would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a ListView. Subclass it and overload the getItem() method to render each column of the table row. You can then easily bind the listview to your data sources. you'll need to create an XML layout resource to describe a row of the table.

To show one table above another, put the listviews inside a RelativeLayout and specify attributes to position them relative to each other.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do it using listview. But still one question stuck in my mind that why listview is preffered over the grid view or table layout for this kind of UI.

Comment: The GridView is designed for table cells that are the same across and down (like a photo gallery) where each cell is a data item. You are creating a table where each *row* is a data item, for which the ListView is most suitable.